# Aggregate by Hour in the mongodb-async-driver

Tags: java, mongodb, asynchronous, driver

How can I aggregate by Hour in the mongodb-async-driver (http://www.allanbank.com/mongodb-async-driver/usage.html)

I have an ISODate-Field in my Collection.

```
[
  { name = "a", date = ISODate(...)},
  { name = "b", date = ISODate(...)},
  ...
]
```

I want to display a graph of how may documents occur per hour.
in the MongoDB-Console. I would do something like this:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([{$group : {_id : {day:{ $hour : "$date"}}, count: { $sum: 1 }}}])
```

but I get stuck at the driver-api:

```
 import static com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.AggregationGroupField.set;
 import static com.allanbank.mongodb.builder.AggregationGroupId.id;

 Aggregate.Builder builder = new Aggregate.Builder();
 builder.group(id().add(???), set("pop").sum("pop"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of the [Expressions](http://www.allanbank.com/mongodb-async-driver/apidocs/com/allanbank/mongodb/builder/expression/Expressions.html) class. Make use of the `group` method that takes a `Builder` and the `AggregationGroupField` array as input.

```
public Aggregate.Builder group(AggregationGroupId.Builder id,
                      AggregationGroupField... aggregations)
```

Build the `hour` Expression and pass it as the id.

```
    Builder hour = new Builder();
    hour.add(Expressions.set("day",Expressions.hour(Expressions.field("date"))));
    Aggregate.Builder builder = Aggregate.builder();
    builder.group(
       hour,
       AggregationGroupField.set("pop").sum("pop")
      );
    MongoIterator<Document> result = col.aggregate(builder);
    while(result.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(result.next());
    };
```